# In TCPDF, bookmarks only work in IE

Tags: php, tcpdf

According to the documentation in this source code:

[TCPDF Example 15](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_015.phps)

It would be possible to move to a specific page by passing the bookmark in the URL: 
[Target Chapter 2](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_015.pdf#chapter2).
However, it works only in IE.

Am I missing something or that IS actually the case?

Comment: I was expecting to get the hash working in FF. Shouldn't I?

Comment: does it work for other PDFs? eg try a bunch of arbitrary PDFs on the web. This way you can rule out PHP and TCPDF from the question. It sounds like it's just a browser feature in the built-in PDF viewer that is supported by IE but not by other browsers.

Comment: It IS a TCPDF problem as I have created PDFs with MSWord and they all work well.